# How to Add Web Server to Server Farm?

Tags: sharepoint-server, configuration-wizard, sharepoint-farm, farm-setup, psconfig

This is my first time creating a multi-tier server farm for our company and I am trying to add our Web Server to our SharePoint server farm.

When I try to run the product configuration from our Web Server - I receive an error message that it fails to connect to the server. We check the logs and it looks like we are getting an access denied. I clicked on the "Help" button and I believe it's because the database has already been created so we have to use PSConfig from the CMD line?

I'm on the Farm Account on our Farm server. I enter in the script and it is successful but I cannot see our web server added. I know this is incorrect because the server we are trying to add is our web server and nowhere on that script has our web server mentioned.

Our farm account does not have an account/access with our web server and I try entering the same script from our webserver and it's telling me I don't have the permissions but the account I logged in with has DBO access to the Farm Server.

I've been trying to find information online and I have been working on this portion for about 2 weeks but nothing seems to work. Can anyone help lead me towards the right direction?

Another Note: Settings wise - We previously had this portion working and our web server was linked to our farm server but our farm server crashed and we had to get it replaced. The employee who was working on this project left so I have been assigned to work on this now.

EDIT:

Settings for our config database with our farm account. I am able to use PSconfig and add a server but i have only tested it adding the same server that is already added. 
[image]

Both my user name and shptAdmin are dbo on the Config server - It says dbo on default scheme but the db_owner is not checked and when I try to change that I receive the 15151 error : cannot alter the role 'db_owner', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

And when I try to match the above picture I get that error message as well. 
[image]

Error I receive when I enter User Credentials
[image: hello]

Error I receive when I just enter the passphrase
[image]

Error Updates:

Users who under the sysadm role.
[image]

Error Message I receive when I try to switch over DBO to shptarsAdmin
[image]
[image]

Updated shptarsAdmin - settings - DBO for the config server. 
[image]

Log of the Error I receive when I run the products config wizard
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68555/discussion-on-question-by-xjewlz-how-to-add-web-server-to-server-farm).

Answer (score 0):

In order to add a server in the farm you have to follow these steps:

- Prepare the server (Install SharePoint with same CU level as your farm is)
- Make sure You login on the server with the account having local admin on new server and SQL permission (dbo on config db).
- You ran the PSConfig wizard on the database setting page, enter the DB server and make sure you are selecting the correct db, then enter the Farm account credential ( the account running SharePoint timer service on existing server).

check complete detail here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0926f63d-8dae-44c0-9e91-51209aa4c3ef(v=office.16)#addserver

If you still seeing the issue, please share the screen shot / error logs.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68554/discussion-on-answer-by-waqas-sarwar-mvp-how-to-add-web-server-to-server-farm).